# Net Core 2.1 won't startup because Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation is missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to start an older ASP NET Core 2.1 project without any luck. I constantly get the following error during startup:

```
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[11]
      Hosting startup assembly exception
System.InvalidOperationException: Startup assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation failed to execute. See the inner exception for more details. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, IntPtr ptrLoadContextBinder)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, IntPtr ptrLoadContextBinder)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
```

I have other 2.1 projects without any problems. I compared all settings and NuGet packages, they look equal.

What do I oversee here?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Nuget package for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation?

Comment: The thing is: it’s not even installed! And if I would try it to install it keeps telling me it requires NetCoreApp 3.0 at least.

Comment: Yeah, the package is no longer available for .NET Core 2.1  You'll have to remove it to get the project to build.  Details are in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove Razor Runtime Compilation from your project because the Nuget package is no longer available for .NET Core 2.1.

In the ConfigureServices method of your Startup.cs file, remove any occurrence of this command: `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()`.

Also, remove any reference to the package from your .csproj file.

Comment: You brought me to it!! I did not have any references anywhere, no NuGet, no source. BUT, when I searched for "RuntimeCompilation" in my project, I found it. It was setup as a hosting startup assembly in launchsettings.json. Removed the following line and it worked!!!


        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"

Comment: Woohoo! I'm glad it's working for you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Nuget package for the razor file compilation?

If you do, try including this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    
        //your code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check nuget package versions. They must not be higher than 2.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).